# Is there middle ground between choosing one class of objects and using id in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, object, interface, implementation

when writing interface and implementation files, is there a middle found between choosing one class of objects to use as arguments or to be returned and using id? That is, can I choose a collection of classes that could be used instead of just one specific one or any object type (id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify that the Objective-C type must conform to a protocol. `NSObject` is both a class and a protocol. So, one idea would be to specify `id<NSObject>`.

Or, alternatively, have your protocol extend the `NSObject` protocol. You'll need that if you want use of methods such as `respondsToSelector`.

Comment: I didn't even realize that I wanted to use respondToSelector until you suggested it and I looked it up.

Comment: no worries! Yep, it's standard practice to call that before doing performSelector on a delegate

Comment: If you are using a design pattern (outside of @protocol with @optional methods) that requires significant use of `respondsToSelector:` or `isKindOfClass:`, your architecture is likely sub-optimal or, at the least, very much outside the norm.   In general, you should very rarely need to use either raw `id` as a type or use introspection.

Comment: I thought established practice for delegates was to check first with `respondsToSelector:` before calling a method. I see it everywhere including in Apple's sample code and documentation. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

You could choose a common superclass, or a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) if the valid classes all implement a protocol.